# Run a PHP CRON Job on CPanel from a Different Timezone

Tags: timezone, cron, cpanel

I'm trying to run a PHP script from CRON every 15 minutes from 9AM to 6PM during Monday to Friday. My problem is the server is set to CST and my client is on GMT+8. I believe (please do correct me if I'm mistaken) we have a time difference of 13 hours. I'd like to check if the following settings are correct:

```
*/15    20-23   *   *   2-7 wget -O - http://www.mysite.com/myscript.html
*/15    00-05   *   *   2-7 wget -O - http://www.mysite.com/myscript.html
```

Pardon me. This is the first time I'm using CRON.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Basically it runs on local machine clocking system. You should launch something like * * * * * /usr/local/php /tmp/yourscript.php  and your script should checkout the timezone issues to reject or allow.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. The scripts are on the same server as the server where the site runs, which are on CST zone. We'd like to run the CRON job on Asia/Manila time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have looks OK except when daylight saving time changes occur.  What will you do then?  One option is to expand your window by an hour so that you run the job for an extra hour on one side during winter and the other side during summer.  If that's not OK for some reason, you'll need to either change the server's timezone, change your script to check the time, or use this patch from OpenSolaris, which adds special TZ support to cron:

http://blogs.oracle.com/chrisg/entry/timezone_aware_cron_finally_pushed

Comment: +1 Sadly, I'm only have limited access to the server but your answer makes real sense. Thank you very much. Upped+ and Accepted!